# Sorting query results by the number of votes (associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a website which has a ranking system similar to stackoverflow. Specifically, Questions can be upvoted or downvoted. The Question's score is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes. In my application, Vote belongs_to :question and has a boolean :upvote to determine whether it's an upvote or a downvote. I was wondering if I can make a named scope to sort by score.

The SQL equivalent would be something like

SELECT *
FROM Question q
ORDER BY ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes v1 WHERE v1.question_id = q.id AND v1.upvote = true) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes v2 WHERE v2.question_id = q.id AND v2.upvote = false) ) DESC

But I am not sure how to put this into Rails. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier if you store vote value (+1 or -1) instead of bool, then you could just sum over this field.

Comment: This is a great idea, klew. How would I make the ordering work in a named scope if I did this?

Comment: Did get a solution for your problem, if so can you plz post it or email me . really appreciate your help here . I am dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute([your long query here]) too rough a solution?

Comment: It is too rough, unfortunately. I need to be able to chain together several named_scopes

Answer (score 0):

```
Votes
  scope :upvote, where("votes.upvote = ? ", true)
  scope :downvote, where("votes.upvote = ? ", false)

q.votes.upvote.count - q.votes.downvote.count
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I'm not the asker of this post), but could you had a :counter_cache for each line of scope ? That way the query will be a one liner.

Comment: This will give me the score of a question, but it won't order it, which is that I need. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I can think of an oracle way of doing it with using

```
scope :net_count, where("sum(decode(votes.upvote,true,1,false,-1))")
```

Not sure if that would be very portable to other databases though.

There are plenty of nice way to do it in ruby/rails though, but cant think of any other which are purely "one scope".